# Can we use NOT IN on multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, where-clause

I am creating a stored procedure (with Sql Server) involving a single table.

I'd like to apply the conditions in my WHERE clause to a pair of columns.  i.e. I would like something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE afficherCreationLuns (@start DATE, @end DATE)
                    AS
                    SELECT dateMin = MIN(t1.dateCollecte), displayName, label,     date = DATEADD(day, -1, MIN(dateCollecte)), capacityInKB = MIN(capacityInKB)
                    FROM Vsp 
                    WHERE dateCollecte > @start AND dateCollecte <= @end
                                    AND (label, displayName) NOT IN (SELECT label, displayName
                                                            FROM Vsp 
                                                            WHERE dateCollecte = @start)

                    GROUP BY displayName, label
```

After some research, I changed the code to use the EXISTS clause, which seemed better suit my needs.  Here is what I have now:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE afficherCreationLuns (@start DATE, @end DATE)
                    AS
                    SELECT dateMin = MIN(t1.dateCollecte), t1.displayName, t1.label, date = DATEADD(day, -1, MIN(t1.dateCollecte)), capacityInKB = MIN(t1.capacityInKB)
                    FROM Vsp t1
                    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT t2.displayName, t2.label
                                    FROM Vsp t2
                                    WHERE t1.displayName = t2.displayName AND t1.label = t2.label AND t2.dateCollecte > @start AND t2.dateCollecte <= @end
                                    AND (t1.label NOT IN (SELECT t3.label
                                                            FROM Vsp t3
                                                            WHERE t3.dateCollecte = @start)
                                    OR t1.displayName NOT IN (SELECT t4.displayName
                                                                    FROM Vsp t4
                                                                    WHERE t4.dateCollecte = @start) ) )
                    GROUP BY t1.displayName, t1.label
```

But it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `NOT IN` with `NOT EXISTS`, like this:

```
SELECT
    dateMin = MIN(t1.dateCollecte)
,   t1.displayName
,   t1.label
,   date = DATEADD(day, -1, MIN(t1.dateCollecte))
,   capacityInKB = MIN(t1.capacityInKB)
FROM Vsp t1
WHERE t1.dateCollecte > @start
  AND t1.dateCollecte <= @end
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Vsp t2
    WHERE t2.dateCollecte = @start
      AND t2.label=t1.label
      AND t2.displayName=t1.displayName
  )
GROUP BY t1.displayName, t1.label
```

The idea is to run the inner select with the additional condition that matches `label` and `displayName` to the corresponding fields of the outer select, and drop records of the outer select where such a match can be found.

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate the two columns together? Like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE COLUMN1+' '+COLUMN2
    NOT IN (
        SELECT COLUMN1+' '+COLUMN2
            FROM [OTHER-TABLE])
```

Thanks.

Comment: This approach can produce unexpected results when concatenated results give you false aliasing. For example, you would get a match for pairs `{'quick', 'brown fox'}` and `{'quick brown', 'fox'}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Exists clause that way. I'm not sure about the way to refer to the main VSP table, but I think this where clause should do what you want.

WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Vsp WHERE dateCollecte = @start AND label=Vsp.label AND displayName=Vsp.displayName)